# xml transformation with xsl-beginner

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform a simple xml using xsl. I know there are many examples on this site, but if anyone can help me go to the next step.

This is the source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
  <cars>
    <car>
      <id>1</id>
      <brand>Audi</brand>
      <type>A3</type>
      <license>TST</license>
    </car>
  </cars>
  <distances>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110901</date>
      <distance>111</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110902</date>
      <distance>23</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110903</date>
      <distance>10</distance>
    </distance>
  </distances>
</output>
```

---

XSL result will be this (results) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
  <cars>
    <car>
      <id>1</id>
      <brand>Audi</brand>
      <type>A3</type>
      <license>TST</license>
      <distances>
        <distance day="20110901">111</distance>
        <distance day="20110902">23</distance>
        <distance day="20110903">10</distance>
      </distances>
    </car>
  </cars>
```

Tthis is the last xsl. Something is missing, because it does not work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:key name="Dist_car" match="distances/distance" use="id_car" />
<xsl:template match="car">
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <distances>    
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Dist_car', id)"/>
         </distances>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="distances">
        <distance day="{date}"><xsl:value-of select="distance"/></distance>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by defining a *key* to map a car ID to its set of `distance` elements

```
<xsl:key name="distancesForCar" match="distances/distance" use="id_car" />
```

Now when you are processing a particular `car` element you can extract the matching `distance` elements using `key('distancesForCar', id)`.

For the main structure of the stylesheet I would recommend you start with an *identity template* (there are many many examples of this on Stack Overflow) which copies the input to output unchanged.  Next you add specific templates to ignore the `distances` element

```
<xsl:template match="distances"/>
```

and to append the required `<distance day="...">...</distance>` elements to the end of each `car`

```
<xsl:template match="car">
  <!-- copy as the identity template would -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <!-- but add distances before the end tag -->
    <distances>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('distancesForCar', id)"/>
    </distances>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="distance">
  <distance day="{date}">
    <xsl:value-of select="distance"/>
  </distance>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      version="1.0"> <xsl:key name="distancesForCar" match="distances/distance" use="id_car" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>'  this copy the whole xml...i tested, but i don't understand where to put the "key"  '<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('distancesForCar', 'id')">
         <dist>
         <xsl:value-of select="@distance"/>
         </dist>'        thank you

Comment: @user3209696 seeing as you've shown some effort, I've spelled out the remaining steps in more detail.

Comment: it's much better... i tried to validate the code (with free-online-transformer), and i think it's not 100% correct... if you have some time to look again. In the source, I have <output/cars/car> and for the other node <output/distances/distance> . I think it'a a problem with the first match="car" or the "key". Why you omit the **distances** node ?    i put the whole xsl in the edit.

Comment: @user3209696 Sorry, I missed that you wanted a `distances` element around the `distance` ones - that can be done simply by wrapping one around the `apply-templates`.  The empty `<xsl:template match="distances"/>` is so you don't get the original top-level `distances` element after `cars` in the output.

Comment: @user3209696 P.S. if you want to add extra detail it would be better to edit the original question rather than my answer.

Comment: hello again :) your answers was very usseful.... but, if you explain how to group for each id_car the '<distances> <distance> day = {date}> distance </distance> </distances>' like in the output. In the car node, at the end, apear the distances node... What do you mean with : _The empty <xsl:template match="distances"/>_ .

Comment: @user3209696 compare my answer with your version - the template in my version that matches `distance` is in your version matching `distances` (plural) instead.